# Ruby classes with namespaces

Tags: ruby

Why is this not legal name-spacing ?    We use this often with our ActiveRecord classes.   Does AR do something magical?

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p194 :001 > class F::B
1.9.3-p194 :002?>   end
NameError: uninitialized constant F
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: first do `module F ;end` then `class F::B;end`..

Answer (score 1):

#### Because `F` is not defined before you reference it.

You must first define `F` as a Class or Module.  Try this:

```ruby
module F; end # OR class F; end
class F::B; end
f = F::B.new # => #<F::B:0x007fba3c1046d8>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forgetting about [modules](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm).

```
1.9.3p429 :001 > module F
1.9.3p429 :002?>   class B
1.9.3p429 :003?>   end
1.9.3p429 :004?> end
 => nil
1.9.3p429 :005 > F::B.new
 => #<F::B:0x0000000082a230>
1.9.3p429 :006 >
```

If the module is defined before the class, it will work:

```
module F; end
class F::B; end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > module F;end
 => nil 
2.0.0p247 :002 > class F::B;end
 => nil 
2.0.0p247 :003 > F
 => F 
2.0.0p247 :004 > F::B
 => F::B
```